# Scaling has not been happening from the center point

Tags: mesh, node-editor, objects, edit-mode, scale

I am very new to blender and this could be a silly one for the pros here.

While **scaling**, I prefer the reference point to which scaling happens, to be the center point of all selected vertices. But then for some reason, scaling happens with reference to one of the selected vertices. How do I fix this?

[image: Scaling from the white vertex in the picture, but how do I make it happen from the center point?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the *Pivot Center* option, instead of *Active Element*, choose *Median Point*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @moonboots, it worked. Thumbs up.